# How to delete a node in a linked list, based off a string

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

As the title implies.  Deleting the first node in the linked list works like a charm.  It's those other dang nodes!  Ok, so here is my code.  I think I am deleting properly, but I am not linking correctly.

Here is what the structs and typedefs look like:

```
typedef struct List *ListP;
typedef struct Entry *EntryP;
typedef char *ListItemP;

struct List
{
    int sizeL;
    struct Entry *head;
};

struct Entry
{
    ListItemP content;
    struct Entry *next;
    int sizeL;
};
```

The way that the removeItemList function works in main.c is is by passing a list pointer (ListP thisList) and a string (ListItemP thisItem).  Once the parameters have been passed, the function searches for the same string as a node in the list (via strcmp()) and when it finds it removes it.  NewEntry initialized Entry struct and has an input that passes a character to newEntry->content.  Anyways, here is the function :

```
void removeItemList(ListP thisList, ListItemP thisItem)
{
    EntryP temp = newEntry(0x00);
    EntryP temp2 = newEntry(0x00);

    temp->next = thisList->head;
    temp2->next = thisList->head;
    if (strcmp(temp->next->content, thisItem) == 0)
    {
        thisList->head = temp->next->next;
    }
    else {
         while(temp->next != 0x00)
         {
            if(strcmp(temp->next->content,thisItem) == 0) {
                break;
            }
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            temp->sizeL++;
         }
        if (temp->next == 0x00) {
        }
        else {
            int i = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < temp->sizeL - 1 ; i++)
            {
                temp2->next = temp2->next->next;
                printf("%s \n", temp2->content);
            }
            temp2->next = temp->next->next;
            free(temp2->next);
        }
    }
    thisList->sizeL--;
}
```

I think that the node before the node being removed winds up being pointed to null.  I am having trouble figuring out how to fix that, though.  I guess that's why I'm here!  Anything will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

EDIT: UPDATED CODE, PLUS DIPLAY LIST CODE

Updated removeItemList()

```
void removeItemList(ListP thisList, ListItemP thisItem)
{
    EntryP current = newEntry(0x00);
    EntryP prev = newEntry(0x00);

    prev = 0x00;
    current = thisList->head;

    if (strcmp(current->content, thisItem) == 0)
    {
        thisList->head = current->next->next;
    }
    else {

        while (current->next != 0x00)
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
            if (strcmp(current->content, thisItem) == 0)
            {   
                prev->next = current->next;
                free(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DisplayList():

```
void displayList(ListP thisList)
{   
    EntryP temp = newEntry(0x00);
    temp->next = thisList->head;
    while(temp->next != 0x00)
    {
       printf("%s \n", temp->next->content);
       temp->next = temp->next->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

If I were to just use printf() statements, I can access everything just fine and the node seems deleted.  However, if I'm trying to print them with displayList(), I get a segfault after printing the node before the one being deleted.  So it seems as if I'm not linking the nodes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For deleting any intermediate nodes, maintain two pointers to the list, prev and cur. Initialize prev to null and cur to the head of the list. Now traverse the list until you meet the node to be deleted. Before moving to the next node in the analysis, reassign prev to cur and cur to cur->next.
When the required node is reached, do

```
prev->next = cur->next;
free(cur);

return;// If necessary.
```

Entire pseudocode:

```
prev = null;
cur = list->head;

while(cur!=null)
{
   if(//This is the node to be deleted)
   {
        prev->next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        return;
   }

   prev = cur;
   cur = cur->next;

}
//Node not found case
```

Now integrate this scenario into your code, and you should be fine. Before this, just check explicitly for the first node though, as this won't fit into the above use case.

**UPDATE**: I noticed a few bugs in your function DisplayList(). Why are you analysing with temp->next during traversal? Seems like a roundabout method to me. Just analyse with temp.

```
void displayList(ListP thisList)
{   
    EntryP temp = thisList->head;
    while(temp!= 0x00)
    {
      printf("%s \n", temp->content);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

And why were you freeing the temp node during the list display? If you just want to display the list contents, freeing the node doesn't make any sense acc. to me.

Comment: So, if I were to use simple printf statements, everything in my list is there.  However, if I access it with a function like

Comment: Please post your complete query so that I can try and help u